# How to hide button icon on load in Sencha conditionally

Tags: javascript, button, extjs

I don't have much experience with Sencha, but I have to make an icon of a button ("alert", with no handler) in a grid show or hide conditionally for every row, depending on a value that I get from an API in the store. I've tried using "bind:" and "listeners" but I couldn't get there.
I can hide it with a handler and such, but I want it to hide or show conditionally when the page loads. This is to work as a warning that a value is set to low. I tried to bind it to a function in the controller but I couldn't get it to fire.

Here is my grid:

```
 requires: [
    'Ext.grid.column.Action'
],

bind: {
    store: '{BackgroundJobsMonitoringStore}'
},

plugins: 'gridfilters',
stateful: true,
stateId: 'stateGrid',
headerBorders: false,

actions: {
    run: {
        iconCls: 'u4f-backgroundjobs-start-icon',
        tooltip: U4.Titles.getTitle(20637, 'Run'),
        handler: 'onRunClick',
        isActionDisabled: 'isRunDisabled'
    },
    // pause: {
    //     iconCls: 'u4f-backgroundjobs-pause-icon',
    //     tooltip: U4.Titles.getTitle(60600, 'Hold'),
    //     handler: 'onPauseClick'
    // },
    kill: {
        iconCls: 'u4f-backgroundjobs-kill-icon',
        tooltip: U4.Titles.getTitle(39340, 'Terminate'),
        handler: 'onKillClick',
        isActionDisabled: 'isKillDisabled'
    },
    alert: {
        iconCls: 'u4f-backgroundjobs-kill-icon',
        tooltip: U4.Titles.getTitle(-1, 'Attention: Full log enabled!'),
        reference: 'alertButton',
},

columns: [
    {
        text: U4.Titles.getTitle(44499, 'Job ID'),
        flex: 4,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'jobId',
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    },
    {
        text: U4.Titles.getTitle(60247, 'Last update') + ' (UTC)',
        flex: 4,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'updatedAt',
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        xtype:'datecolumn', 
        format:'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    },
    {
        text: U4.Titles.getTitle(338731, 'Status'),
        xtype: 'u4f_bjstatusbadge',
        flex: 2,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'status',
        filter: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        align: 'center'
    }, 
    {
        text: U4.Titles.getTitle(47035, 'Actions'),
        menuDisabled: true,
        sortable: false,
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        flex: 2,
        // items: ['@run', '@pause', '@kill'],
        items: ['@alert','@run', '@kill'],
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        align: 'center'
    }
],

listeners: {
    cellclick: 'openLoggingWindow',
    afterrender: 'onAfterRender',
}
```

});

Here is my function example to get the value I want to use:

```
isLow: function (grid, rowIndex) {
    var me = this,
        gridStore = grid.getStore(),
        storedTask = gridStore.getAt(rowIndex),
        jobId = storedTask.get('jobId');


    gridStore.sendConfigTaskRequest(jobId)
        .then(function (response) {
            var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            return data.LogLevel !== "Low";
            
        })
        .otherwise(function () {
            me.manageError(action, jobId);
        });
},
```

How can I implement this in the controller and/or grid?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a data property from the grid row (the record) to determine  whether to show or hide something for each row. This is the `jobId` field. You also need the store in your `isLow` function but nothing else.

So first I would recommend the refactor your `isLow` function to take `jobId` and `store` as parameters (you don't really need the grid, and it is always a good idea to separate logic from UI anyway)

```
isLow: function (gridStore, jobId) {
  var me = this;

  gridStore.sendConfigTaskRequest(jobId)
    .then(function (response) {
        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        return data.LogLevel !== "Low";
            
     })
    .otherwise(function () {
         me.manageError(action, jobId);
     });
},
```

You have both these function parameters available from the `renderer`. All you need to do is to call it for each row and return either an icon or empty string. Here is an example fiddle code, you can try to [run the fiddle on the link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3n3s).

I added both `renderer` and `widgetcolumn` solutions, there are slight differences but both can be used.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'jobId'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        jobId: 1000
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        jobId: 1001
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        jobId: 1002
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        jobId: 1003
    }]
});

Ext.create({
    xtype: 'grid',
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 3,
    }, {
        text: 'jobId',
        dataIndex: 'jobId',
        flex: 2,
    }, {
        text: 'isLow',
        align: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
            if (isLow(store, record.get('jobId'))) {
                return '<span class="x-fa fa-check">';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
        text: 'isNotLow',
        widget: {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'x-fa fa-times',
            text: '',
            disabled: true,
            handler: function (button, event) {},
        },
        onWidgetAttach: function (col, widget, record) {
            if (isLow(record.store, record.get('jobId'))) {
                widget.hide();
            }
        },
        flex: 1,
        align: 'center',
        menuDisabled: true,
        sortable: false,
    }],
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

function isLow(gridStore, jobId) {
    // do your own logic here
    return jobId == 1001 || jobId == 1003;
}
```

You don't need to display the `jobId` column, you only need to have it in the store. Hope it helps!

Comment: When you call isLow(store, record.get('jobId')) is it using the isLow function from the controller which is accessing the API? Because although I need a jobId, the deciding factor for "icon or no icon" is the response from the API.
I'm getting a "isLow" is not defined since it's not being able to access the controller, I think.

Comment: I don't know where is your function defined but you can access it as you would access any JavaScript function. From you view from example you can call `this.getController()` to access the controller etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use a [widgetcolumn](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html) with a custom `onWidgetAttach` function. It works the best if you have the data already in the loaded store but you can execute other logic as well.

Something like:

```
columns: [{
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    text: '...',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'button',
        iconCls: ...
        handler: ...,
    },
    onWidgetAttach: function(col, widget, record) {
        // if you don't need a text on the button
        widget.setText('');
        if (...) {
            widget.hide();
        }
    },
    flex: 1,
    align: 'center',
    menuDisabled: true,
    sortable: false,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I can't really add a new column to this grid. I have to use the actions column to achieve the purpose. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I am afraid that is problematic, if you want to hide the button. You can disable it as you do in your code, but to change the column configuration you need to use `reconfigure` method of grid but you can't have a different column configuration for different rows.

Comment: One thing you can try is to use a custom `renderer` function for this action column and try to add an icon (button) there.

Comment: I've tried everything and still cannot do it properly.
I'll accept your answer since that's probably the best way to approach the problem.
I'll try to change the icon for another one conditionally instead of hiding it but I have no idea how to. Probably it's best to open another question.
Thank you for the input.

Comment: You are welcome, but you don't need the accept my answer if it does not help you. If you can create a minimal example with Sencha Fiddle I can look into it and try to help.

Comment: For example it is possible to try to add a custom CSS style with `display: none;` and assign this style to the appropriate DOM element row by row.

Comment: I'm trying to set it to hide or show depending on a value I get from the API in the store. Still struggling. 
I'd like to use fiddle but I'm a beginner with Sencha.
I've been messing around with the CSS. I managed to make the icon unclickable, less opaque and with no cursor interaction, but only for the whole column, not row by row depending on the value I get from the API. I have a function called "isLow" that returns true or false in the controller. Could you show me how to implement the switch between styles using this controller function? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is hard to do it without seeing your code. But there is a `renderer` config which you can use in a column the adjust how the cell is displayed for each individual row. See [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer).

Comment: Here if you use the input `metaData.tdCls` or `metaData.tdStyle` you can assign CSS formatting to the cell contents. I would look around this.

Comment: I'm sorry. Been busy working on other stuff.
My controller function takes grid and rowIndex as parameters.
The renderer also takes in the rowIndex but no grid. I'm not sure how I would define the renderer function to use isLow function from the controller to decide wether to render the icon or not. I can do it in a new column if it's easier. Can you help me with that? You can submit as an answer because it would probably fix my problem on the spot.
Thank you in advance.